# My site built on information from Wikipedia was rejected by google for AdSense - We found some policy violations on your site

Tags: seo, google, google-adsense, copyright

A few months ago I published one of mine website and it is completely based on cricket result and team prediction, news, and facts. The source of information which I am using is completely from Wikipedia, and I have not used even a single photograph either of any cricketer nor any logo.

When I applied for Adsense, I got this message from google

```
We found some policy violations on your site
```

I can't understand that what kind of copyright issue they are?

I also have given the reference to the source of information of Wikipedia in the footer on my website.

Please help me in understanding what is causing this copyright issue.

Comment: And what is the website address? since it's doubtful your going to get any more feedback from users without further information.

Comment: These days, Adsense tends to only approve pages that are completely unique content, particularly articles and blog posts. Any pages that largely have content that can be found on other sites seem to usually get denied by Adsense. You can ask for more help in the Google Adsense help forum, but it's tough to get replies from experts in Adsense there

Answer (score 3):

The [AdSense quality guidelines state](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348737?hl=en&ref_topic=1261918):

> - Make sure your site adds value. Publishers are not allowed to create multiple pages, sub-domains, or domains with substantially [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359).
> - Publishers must provide [unique and relevant content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66361) that gives users a reason to visit their site first.

If you have built your site only with content from Wikipedia, Google feels your site doesn't add enough value to warrant ads.

In general, you need 50 pages of original, well written content before you apply to Google AdSense.

Comment: Thanks For your response! Just to add few more things to it.

I have enough number of users to this site, daily visitors count is more than 1000 and also the content is very much relevant to users.

Also as i have not copied the content from Wikipedia just that information or you can say facts I have used from there else entirely content is uniquely written by me only.

That's why I am so confusion that what type of copyright issue google is talking about

Comment: When a Google reviewer comes to look at your site, they often visit the home page and click to one other page.   To get AdSense you have to make it very clear from the home page that you have everything they want.   You need clear navigation to 10s of original content pages directly from the home page.   You need good grammar and spelling.  You need a professional looking color scheme and theme.   Your site needs to load quickly.   From what I've seen, Google's reviewers often deny sites based on impressions rather than on specific policy problems.

Comment: Thanks for your response Stephen, but my question still remains the question, can we use Wikipedia content to our website without any copyright issue??

Comment: It isn't an issue of copyright.  Wikipedia gives you a license to use their content as long as you abide by the terms:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights   But just because you can use the content legally, it doesn't mean that Google wants to put ads on it.   Google's policy is that content for ads must be original and add value.   I would make sure that no syndicated or copied content is prominent on your site during an AdSense review.

Comment: Yup, I agree with you and that is why just the content or you can say facts I have copied from Wikipedia, not the exact source code, further I have added my own analysis algorithm and created some very useful content for end user, and that is the result getting more than 1000 unique users every day. I wish I could understand this policy violation issue.